# How to change GAE local server's login in user account?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, account

There is an edit page on my GAE app only the admin can log in. It works well on GAE server. But on the local dev machine, when I go to

```
http://localhost:9080/editpage
```

it says

```
Current logged in user test@example.com is not authorized to view this page.
```

How can I change test@example.com to my admin account?

I use python.

Answer (score 8):

You can go directly to /_ah/login and change who you're logged in as. (Or to log out, or to change user/admin-status.)

Comment: Yes, use this link http://localhost:9080/_ah/login can change the login status directly without deleting any brower data. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have already logged-in as test@example user, clear browser data and try again.

In the login page, check the checkbox "Sign in as Administrator" to login as admin.

Comment: But how about if I just want to change a user account without deleting the cache and browser data?

Comment: I told you to clear cache because user is not logged out. Otherwise on login, you would have seen the login form where you can change user account. Try once you will get to know.